# Ugly IF conditions : Which way is preferred for code-readability?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So for example,

Code A :

```
def am_I_smart() :

    def check_IQ():
        return very_less_readable_nested_json["name"]["status"]["brain"]["codenumber"]["wowbad"]["IQ"] > 110

    def are_you_ok() :
        return very_less_readable_nested_json["name"]["status"]["brain"] == 'OK'

    if check_IQ() and are_you_ok() :
        return True

    return False
```

Or
Code B:

```
def am_I_smart() :

    if very_less_readable_nested_json["name"]["status"]["brain"]["codenumber"]["wowbad"]["IQ"] > 110
             and very_less_readable_nested_json["name"]["status"]["brain"] == 'OK' :

        return True

    return False
```

and Maybe Code C:

```
def am_I_smart() :

    person = very_less_readable_nested_json["name"]
    brain_status = person["status"]["brain"]
    IQ = brain_status["codenumber"]["wowbad"]["IQ"]

    if IQ > 110 and brain_status == 'OK' :
        return True

    return False
```

Which is probably the most pythonic, or conventional way of dealing with this kind of problem?
Or is there any other preferred way of dealing with nested json-originated dict for readbility?

Comment: At least use `return condition` instead if `if condition: return True   return False`

Comment: Something doesn't add-up... You are checking if `brain_status == 'OK'` but then also doing `IQ = brain_status["codenumber"]["wowbad"]["IQ"]`. So is `brain_status` a string or a dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code C is the best from a readability point of view. You can also make it a bit more simple using

`return IQ > 110 and brain_status == 'OK'`

Aside from this it may make accessing the fields nicer and more readable to convert the JSON back into an object, however I would call C and acceptable solution.

Comment: This is your **opinion** Please avoid answering opinion-based questions as this is not a discussion forum. Answers should rely on facts - this answer is your taste of readability which might not be true for someone else (and even the OP...)